# Is this class a subtype of this other class?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

Suppose there's a class named B and has the method

```
getLength() : Double
```

and there's another class named A with the method

```
getLength() : Number
```

How do I know if class B is a subtype of class A? I know the Class Double is a subtype of Class Number, but it's that enough to verify that class B is a subtype of class A? Thanks ;)

Comment: check for the keyword `extends` in the potential subclass.

Answer (score 3):

unless it is declared as :

```
class B extends A
```

or extends some other class which directly/inderectly extends `A`, it is not a subclass of `A`

you can try:

```
B b = new B();

if ( b instanceof A )
  System.out.println("It is a subclass");
```